# Why cannot import sub module?

Tags: python, python-import

My project structure like this:

```
/project
    main.py
    /a_module
        __init__.py
        /sub_module
            __init__.py
            some_file.py
```

**main.py**

```
from a_module import main_api
```

**a_module/__init__.py**

```
from sub_module import sub_api
```

**sub_module/__init__.py**

```
from some_file import detail_api
```

In **a_module/__init__.py** gives `Unable to import 'sub_module'` error.

Why I cannot import `'sub_module'`?

When I change to the relative path solve the error.

```
from .sub_module import sub_api
```

But I don't understand, does `__init__.py` design for public the API of the module? Why don't treat `sub_module` as a module instead of a directory? it's such a bad design to me...

Comment: sometimes when i face that error i add `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` to the main.py file

Comment: It's not about directory vs module, it's about namespaces (a honking great idea). What if some other package lying around in `sys.path` also wants to use the submodule name "sub_module"? How does the import system determine whether you want that package or the other one? What if you want to access both? If they are not namespaced at all then now you have ambiguity problem.

Comment: @wim does break down project using the relative path is a bad practice?

Comment: No, on the contrary that's the best practice. And you should know the "dots" in Python import statements do not indicate relative path or directory structure, actually, they indicate packages and subpackages/submodules. It just happens that, in the usual case, this corresponds with a directory structure too - but it's not necessarily always the case (e.g. dynamically generated modules, namespace packaging, zip imports...)

Comment: @wim thanks, it is the answer I want.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__.py` is executed when you import the package that contains it. But it's not your problem. Your problem is that **module imports are always absolute unless *explicitly* relative.** That means that they must chain from *some* directory in `sys.path`. By default this includes the working directory, so when you run `main.py` from within `project`, it can find `a_module`, and nothing else.

```
from sub_module import sub_api
```

In `a_module/__init__.py` doesn't work though, because *imports are always absolute unless explicitly relative*. So that import says "starting from some `sys.path` root, find a top level package named `sub_module` and import `sub_api` from it". Since no such module exists you get an error. `from .sub_module import sub_api` works because you opted into relative imports, so it doesn't start over from `sys.path`.

For an example of why you would do this, I'll give you something that broke in our own code back in the Python 2 days before absolute import by default was the law (`from __future__ import absolute_import` enabled the Py3 behavior, which is how we fixed it, but despite what the docs say, it was never enabled by default in Py2, the only enabled by default behavior was relative imports). Our layout was:

```
 teamnamespace/
               module.py
               math/
                    mathrelatedsubmodule.py
                    othermathsubmodule.py
```

Now, we innocently thought hey, we'll put all our packages under a single shared top level namespace, and subpackages cover broad categories within them, and since we had a lot of additional utilities for basic mathematics, we put them under `teamnamespace.math`. Problem was, for the *non*-math modules, like `teamnamespace.module`, when they did:

```
import math  # or
from math import ceil
```

it defaulted to relative lookup, and imported `teamnamespace.math` as `math` (a thoroughly useless import, since it was a namespace package only, all the functionality was in the sub-modules), not the built-in `math` module. In fact, without the Python 3 behavior, there was no reasonable way to get the built-in `math` module from a module under `teamnamespace`. Whereas with the Python 3 behavior, you can get either one or both (by aliasing one or the other with `as`, with no ambiguity:

```
# Gets built-in
import math

# Gets teamnamespace.math
from . import math
```

Comment: The part that says it "defaulted to relative lookup" is not really accurate. In fact that is still an absolute import statement. It happens that it (the absolute import) resolves to a different place in Python 2 (an *implicit relative import*).

Comment: @wim: Absolute imports that are implicitly relative don't sound very absolute to me... The syntax is absolute in the sense that there was no other syntax for a long time, so what is now called "absolute" was the only syntax available prior to explicit relative imports. But it was still preferring relative imports over absolute imports for the same syntax.

Comment: Probably I'm being too nit-picky, but "absolute import" and "relative import" have well-defined meanings for over 10 years now (since v2.5) and the terminology used in the answer is confusing it a bit. Relative imports use leading dots, `import math` can *never* be a relative import (it can resolve within a package in Python 2, but it's still an absolute import). See PEP 328 for the specific details. Now, you say a couple of times here that *imports are always absolute unless explicitly relative* but are you talking about the grammar of the statement, or where the import resolves? Because ...

Comment: ... even in Python 3 modules with stdlib name collisions can still accidentally be resolved under package subdirectories in some cases.  e.g. you execute a .py file from under a package directory, python will add the "script" dir as first entry of `sys.path`. That is going to change where an absolute import such as `import math` gets resolved. It's not an *explicitly relative* import, but it's still resolving inside the package subdir by accident!

Comment: @wim: You're ignoring the actual history when you claim `import math` has always meant absolute. When [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) came about, it explicitly noted the preexisting ambiguity, and specifically noted that the *change* would be to make `import foo` always resolve to a module or package reachable from `sys.path`, which would henceforth be referred to as an absolute import. It's specifically described as "chose absolute imports as the [new] default".

Comment: Your point about executing a `.py` under a package directory is completely unrelated; that actually modifies `sys.path`, so effectively the contents of that package directory are now top-level packages in their own right, so it's still absolute (this makes a difference when relative imports are used in the pseudo-top-level packages that think they're part of the full package). The solution is to not execute `.py` files within packages; replace `python3 package/script.py` with `python3 -m package.script` to avoid that nonsense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208164/discussion-between-shadowranger-and-wim).